# What are these DebugManager and WinIOErrors inside the Workflow invoke method?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, red-gate-ants, ants

I'm running the ANTS Performance Profiler in my windows service to optimize it. So I found out that the execution of one of my workflow is about 436 milliseconds. I drilled down each methods being executed inside the invoke method of my workflow and found the result as shown in the image below.

[image: ANST Performance Profiler Result (Inside the Invoke method of workflow]

What is the DebugManager above? Why is there a WinIOError? Sorry for the noob questions guys I'm just lost here. I really just want to shortened the execution time if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running a debug build from withing VS, never the best way to measure the real performance as that means runtime optimizations are disabled.

Anyway if you are looking for the maximum performance WF4 is not the thing. Due to the asynchronous nature of WF4 execution it is always going to be somewhat hard to predict. And there is always ging to be a bit of overhead with the runtime and all activities involved which means that a simple C# function is always going to run faster.

Comment: Hi Maurice, I'm running a "Release" build from within VS that is why I'm wondering about this.

Comment: Maybe it is always in the stack trace. Never noticed it before but it is way down in the internal parts of WF4.